# Nested command substitutions in a makefile

Tags: makefile

I have a pretty basic makefile where I want to use the name of the current project / folder, but I keep having problems.  I've tried:

```
example:
  docker build -t `basename `pwd`` .
  docker build -t `basename $(pwd)` # From what I know $() relates to a variable in makefiles.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

One approach:

```
docker build -t `basename $(PWD)`
```

This, like many environment variables, is all uppercase.

As was pointed out in the comments, this:

```
docker build -t $$(basename $$(pwd))
```

will also work.  This is more akin to your first attempt, where the `pwd` command is used rather than the `PWD` environment variable.

And, this will also work:

```
docker build -t `basename \`pwd\``
```

Comment: Wow... I tried this before but the make output shows up as:
```
docker build -t `basename /home/aosmith/Development/project` .
```

turns out this actually works, I just wasnt paying attention thanks!

Comment: This doesn't answer the (apparent) question it the title, though.If you actually wanted to nest command substitutions, you need to double the dollar signs in order to pass them through to the shell; `$$(basename $$(pwd))`

Comment: $$ solved my issue for this, I guess it's like a Makefile escape char for command substitution.